# Value changed when using $.extend()

Tags: jquery

I am using `$.extend()` to make a copy of a data set. Most time it works OK. But for some certain data set. The copy would be different from the original one.

For example, the following is the code.

```
console.log(dataset[key].data)
var dataTemps = $.extend(true, [], dataset[key]);         
console.log(dataTemps.data);
```

For the first console.log, the log was something like

```
Array[7]=[1,1, null, "academicreport",330, 22, "M.Sc"]
```

But for the second console.log, the log was

```
Array[7]=[1,1, null, NaN,330, 22, "M.Sc"]
```

Does anyone know how the `$.extend` changed the value of `data[3]` from `"academicreport"` to `NaN`?

Comment: And there is no other code between the two `log` calls?

Comment: No, there is no other code between the two log calls. Use Chrome for testing.

Comment: I find out the reason, it all about pointers...

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
var oldArray = ["mip", "map", "mop"];
var newArray = oldArray.slice();
```

for arrays...

the extend is primary used for cloning objects...

Comment: What I am doing is cloning the objects. data is an array of the objects I am cloning....